# Taking care of a dog in Germany

Tags: dogs, house-moving

In early November I'll be moving from Brazil to Stuttgart (Germany) because I've found a job there. All the documentation has already been taken care of and the dog will be allowed to enter the EU in November 2nd. Also, I'm already aware that it will be kinda hard to find an apartment to rent with a dog, even a small and quiet one as my 1 year old, 5.5kg Shih Tzu.

I've been told that Germans tend to be very annoyed by the smallest amount of barks, and I fully understand that. But I've been told that Germans find it "almost criminal" to leave a dog 8 hours a day alone at home. As I'll be working from 9-to-5, that's what will be happening.

Is this going to be an issue, considering that the dog is well used to this, because it already happens here in Brazil? I mean, do neighbors really care about how much time my dog spents alone at home as long as he doesn't bark?

Comment: In general the reactions depend on the neighbourhood. If it is for example a house with majority people who work the whole day, then maybe even some single barks will cause attention by the people who are at home (maybe someone who works at night). But if it is a "loud" house, for example with much children, then the other families will not mind the barking. Only if your dog sounds like crying or suffering, then they will mind that it may be lonely. The best solution would be, to find someone, who likes to do a walk with your dog, or an old lady, where he can stay the day in company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no law forbidding you to leave your dog alone for any amount of time, as long as you care for it and provide food and water.

There are some common rules when owning dogs in Germany:

- In some areas in Germany dogs must be leashed in public spaces. Please research the local rules (http://www.stadtwiki-stuttgart.de/wiki/Hundehalter if you understand German).
- People walking their dogs have the great chance to get to know other people. It's more common for strangers to start small talk when there is a dog or a child involved.
- You should take tiny garbage bags with you when walking your dog to dispose of your dog's turds. In some places there are public turd bag dispensers, but those are most often empty. Leaving your dog's turds lying around might result in angry reactions. You can buy turd bags in grocery stores or drug stores.
- Excessive barking can be a reason to terminate the lease. But for that the barking must be truly excessive. Find more information at https://www.stuttgart.de/item/show/52190 (again in German).

Comment: My dog doesn't ever go outside without a leash. He usually runs after any bird he sees, so it would be kinda dangerous for him to walk without a leash. Also, I'm already used to walking with little garbage bags to collect his poo. And he usually doesn't bark. He only barks if someone comes to my door, and even so only a couple of barks, then gets quiet again. I was wondering what is the correct behavior if the dog is used to peeing only on walls in the street. It is common here is Brazil, but is it common in Germany too?

Comment: @GustavoMP Since it's the natural behavior of dogs to mark objects with their urine, it's a common sight in Germany as well. You should just not let him pee on cars, bicycles or strollers. The amount of barking you describe should be no problem at all.

Comment: Please also note that even for appartments that allow animals (mostly by some big companies like Vonovia) there might be regulations about how long the dog is allowed to be alone. It could happen that if your landlord finds out they revoke the admission to have a dog. Also you need insurance for your dog.

Comment: In the subject of empty dispensers - have read a few times that where I live (Poland) people are sometimes removing a whole load of dog turd bags from these public dispensers and taking them home, just because they are free - and then use them for whatever purpose, like packaging sandwiches for their children (even though these bags are definitely not food-grade).